# Adding an item to a List<CustomClass> which is DataBinded to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Basically what I'am trying to do is to add a new Item into a DataGrid which has a DataBinded List<> to it. I already tried everything I could think of but I always get the "An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source" exception. If someone would help me with this I would be greatful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding items to the data bound List<CustomClass> on a background thread? Then you could use the dispatcher to marshall the Add call to back the UI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> { yourCollection.Add(yourItem); })));
```

Do this for all Add and Remove operations that modify the source collection.

You should also replace the List<CustomClass> with an ObservableCollection<> if you want the DataGrid to get updated automatically as items are added to the source collection. An ObservableCollection provides change notifications but a List doesn't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Also make sure that you are adding items to the source collection rather than to the Items property of the DataGrid control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `EnableCollectionSynchronization` method on your `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Cant seem to find it anywhere

Comment: Go through this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720638/using-bindingoperations-enablecollectionsynchronization.

Comment: Tried the code below but got an exception: "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."                                                                                                                  `object tempEntry = new MOBFile.MOBObject(br);
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(dg.Items, tempEntry);
            lock (tempEntry)
            {
                dg.Items.Add(tempEntry);
            }`