# This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread... while using the dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm-light, dispatcher

So Im developing an addon with a UI that is used inside an application (main application). To make my UI responsive when the main application is working I'm starting my UI in its separate thread like this:

```
    public  void ShowDialog(IIFCConverter ifcConverter)
    {

        thread = new Thread(x =>
        {
            thread.Name = "UI-thread";
            window = new MainWindow();
            var mainViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainWindowViewModel>();
            mainViewModel.SetIFCConverter(x as IIFCConverter);
            ViewModelLocator.MainWindow = window;
            window.ShowDialog();



        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        thread.Start(ifcConverter);

    }
```

The first time I start my addon it all works. The second time I start it and it tries to raise events (like OnCollectionChanged) I get a NotSupportedException with the message: "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread"

This is one of my methods:

```
    private void AddNewFile(AddNewFileMessage obj)
    {
        if (!(obj.Sender is ButtonViewModel)) return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Path)) return;



        var ifcFileViewModel = new IFCFileViewModel(new Common.Model.IFCFile { Path = obj.Path, Active = true });
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
        {
            ListBoxItems.Insert(ListBoxItems.Count - 1, ifcFileViewModel);
        });

    }
```

I get this eventhough Im using the DispatcherHelper from MVVM light.
I have tried using the "normal" dispatcher to, but that gives me the same result.

First of all Im curious to know the mechanics of why its doing this?
I've checked my threads and I can see that the OnOllectionChanged is called from my UI-thread. 
I cant seem to find any differences to the thread structure between the first run (that works) and the following.

[image: OnCollectionChanged called on UI-thread, right?]

Second, what can I do about this?

Things that I've tested that didnt help:

1. Im using the IoC container from MVVM light and its registered as a LocatorProvider, but I create a new IoC container everytime I initialize the UI and set that instance as the LocatorProvider.
2. Im initializing the DispatcherHelper in the constructor of my window. So that should be on the correct thread.
3. Something that does actually work is wrapping the action in a try Catch-block like this:

   ```
   private void AddNewFile(AddNewFileMessage obj)
   {
   if (!(obj.Sender is ButtonViewModel)) return;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Path)) return;



   var ifcFileViewModel = new IFCFileViewModel(new Common.Model.IFCFile { Path = obj.Path, Active = true });

   DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
   {
       try
       {
           ListBoxItems.Insert(ListBoxItems.Count - 1, ifcFileViewModel);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {

       }
   });
   ```

   }

However I find this very ugly and would like to avoid it and why does that even work? Everything seems to work fine when I wrap all my actions in try Catch-blocks.

Comment: I assume that ListBoxITems is owned by the default UI thread and not by your spawned STA thread. Maybe CheckBeginInvokeOnUI is fooled by your thread and tries to access the collection on your own thread instead of on its owner.

Comment: From what I can see your `ViewModel` is created by a thread that is not UI. Change that and your solution will work with either of the dispatchers.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, how do you see that? From the treads window? Or just by the fact that I get the exception?
The ViewModel should be created by the IoC container that is created by a resource Dictionary used in the window. I cannot see how that is created on the wrong thread...
I cannot see how I can do it in a different way...

Comment: `var mainViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainWindowViewModel>();` is created inside the `UI-Thread`, that is different than the calling thread, so the object is owed by a different thread, how can you not see that?

Comment: @XAMlMAX, different from what thread, the UI? The ServiceLocator is set to an object created inside my viewmodellocator that is created by my mainwindow 
Wouldnt that make it the same thread? Thus, the mainviewmodel and the MainWindow is created on the same thread, right? and this is what I want...

Comment: Nope, the viewmodellocator might be created on a different thread but the variable of the viewmodel doesn't belong to the main thread. That's why your Window is not created there. Threads share memory and variables but not ownership.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, firstly, nothing in this is created by the Main thread. Everything sits on a worker thread. Secondly, if I create my IoC container in one thread: why would the instances that the container create not be created on that same thread?
What should I do put the viewmodel on the same thread as my UI?

Comment: Why are you creating the MainWindow on another thread in the first place? When you do this, you won't be able to interact with this window from *any* other thread including the main (dispatcher) thread.

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing here.So to clarify Your IoC is created on `Thread1`, but the view model is created on `Thread2` so the actual variable's owner is `Thread2` NOT `Thread1`.

Comment: @mm8: Since its an addon to main application that will stop responding for extended periods of time and I want to keep my application responsive I have to create it in a separate thread, or atleast thats what I thought...
XAMlMAX: ok, but why is that? Isnt the creator of an object the owner? And why does it work the first time? Is something in my addon being kept alive? Am I forgetting to dispose of something?

Comment: Then you won't be able to interact with the window from *any* other thread so this is pretty pointless in your scenario I guess. A window created on thread B can never be accessed from thread A.

Comment: We are not talking about the owners as in variables, the error that you were getting was about the `Owning Thread`, that's why.

Comment: @mm8: why cant I use the dispatcher to accomplish that?

Comment: To accomplish what? Each window has its own dispatcher.

Comment: @mm8: well this discussion has been going from here to there: what I originally wanted to accomplish was to ensure that the viewmodel and the view are in the same thread. However what I was referring to in my previous comment was to update the my window from my viewmodel when they happen to sit on two different threads.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found the real problem. 
The viewmodel was indeed created on the same thread as my addon UI.

HOWEVER: I was using the Messenger that is avaliable in the MVVMLight toolkit to handle communication between viewmodels and I forgot to unregister the viewmodel when my windows was closed. So the second time I opened my window and started sending messages between my viewmodels. The first viewmodel reacted and that was what was causing the problem. 
That is also why the try-Catch-block worked, because there was a second call from the correct thread that was working. 
I added a datetime to the constructor of the viewmodel and there are indeed two different viewmodels being called. I do not understand why I get that exception. If anything the first viewmodel should be connected via datacontext to the first view. Its like the view has hooked up to the events of two different viewmodels.

Anyway, it works now: I just unregister the viewmodel from the message service when my window is closed and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845(v=vs.110).aspx) and read this topic: [Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720638/using-bindingoperatio-enablecollectionsynchronizationns).