# How to update only a property in an observable collection from thread other than dispatcher thread in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a `class` named `Employee`. I need to update only the property `Status` from thread other than current dispatcher thread:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel (`ViewModelBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface):

```
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


public class DisplayViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public static event EventHandler OnStatusChanged;

    ObservableCollection<Employee> _dailyEmployees;

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> DailyEmployees
    {
        get { return _dailyEmployees; }
        set
        {
            _dailyEmployees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DisplayViewModel()
    {
        OnStatusChanged += DisplayViewModel_OnStatusChanged;
    }

    //invoked in other thread
    private void DisplayViewModel_OnStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = sender as Employee;
        if (d == null)
            return;
        var em = DailyEmployees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == d.Name);

        if(em == null)
        {
            DailyEmployees.Add(em);
        }
        else
        {
            em.Status = d.Status;
        }
    }
}
```

When i tried adding values to observable collection it throws exception as

"This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread"

How shall I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update an ObservableCollection via a worker thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use the dispatcher to call the `Add` method on the UI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => DailyEmployees.Add(em));
```

Or call the [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198861.aspx) method on the UI thread to enable the collection to be used on multiple threads:

```
public class DisplayViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Employee> _dailyEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> DailyEmployees
    {
        get { return _dailyEmployees; }
    }

    public DisplayViewModel()
    {
        System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_dailyEmployees, _lock);
        OnStatusChanged += DisplayViewModel_OnStatusChanged;
    }

    //invoked in other thread
    private void DisplayViewModel_OnStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = sender as Employee;
        if (d == null)
            return;
        var em = DailyEmployees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == d.Name);

        if (em == null)
        {
            DailyEmployees.Add(em);
        }
        else
        {
            em.Status = d.Status;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that the `Employee` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Status` property if you want the value of this one to be reflected in the view when you set it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big problem in your code. First, the ObservableCollection is already a collection that notifies on change, so you not need reinitialize it, just call Clear and Add/Insert.

Second, the Employee class should be ViewModelBase:

```
class Employee: ViewModelBase
{
   private string _status;

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Status
   {
     get
     {
        return _status;
     }
     private set
     {
        _status=value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
     }
   }
}
```

This should allow you to change `DailyEmployees[0].Status="NewStatus";`

LE: In case you have problems changing data from another thread, check this link: [Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720638/using-bindingoperations-enablecollectionsynchronization)

LLE: I used the `ViewModelBase` class for the `Employee`, because it was already used in the code sample. A raw answer would have mean implementing the `class Employee: INotifyPropertyChanged` and implementing the required method.

Comment: _"Employee class should be ViewModelBase"_ - no it should not.  An `Employee` is the _model_ in  _MVVM_ not the _VM_,  All it needs is a `INotifyPropertyChanged`.   The fact that this interface is not implemented is why notifications don't occur.  `ViewModelBase` is incidental

Comment: Just to point out to anyone reading the answer, with less MVVM knowledge. The "ViewModelBase" in the above answer requires the interface INotifyPropertyChanged which allows the employee properties live one-way/two-way updates from the UI. This is facilitated by the "RaisePropertyChanged" method, which should fire the event. As for the issue with updates from a different thread. It should be as simple as "**Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Method(); })**"

Comment: @MickyD I answered using the resources the user has give in the code. He is already using ViewModelBase, that means he has knowledge about it and how to use it. A raw answered would have been as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => /* update value */);`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2092036/8063451)

Comment: Thanks @MickyD, I've updated the answer accordingly.