# Update item in ObservableCollection as Thread safe

Tags: wpf, thread-safety, observablecollection

Is there any good way to update a Item 
in ObservableCollection as "Thread safe" ?

Here is my way.

```
var target = MyCollection.Where(i => i.Key== a_Key).Single();
MyCollection[MyCollection.IndexOf(target)] = NewValue;
```

But I worry. If I use Index, It may not thread safe.. 
Please advice me.

In internet, THere is some thread-safe-ObservableCollection.
I want to use No.1.

Is there any better way ?

1. https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516
2. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection
3. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ParallelExtensionsExtras/
4. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/26d9d070619de58fa8e28ea21fff04fd

**Edit (1)**

When I used index to replace, I have to worry the possibility that other thread change or sort Collection. Index maybe change until I overwrite. Is there the possibility ?

I want to know more good way to update/Overwrite a Collection item.

If there is a way to update/overwrite a item WITHOUT index, Please teach me..

Answer (score 1):

You can only update a data-bound `ObservableCollection<T>` on the dispatcher thread anyway, unless you use the [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) method that was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5.

This method accepts an `object` to lock when accessing the collection. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258222/how-to-update-only-a-property-in-an-observable-collection-from-thread-other-than/51260357#51260357) answer for an example.