# WPF clear ObservableCollection in another thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, observablecollection, dispatch

I have application in WPF and I want to clear ObservableCollection when setter is set from another thread.

This is setter:

```
public List<Model.MasterReview> SelectedMasterReviews
        {
            get { return selectedMasterReviews; }
            set
            {
                selectedChildReview = null;
                selectedMasterReviews = value;

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    GetChildReviews();
                });
            }
        }


private void GetChildReviews()
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                ChildReviews.Clear();
            });
}
```

And I get error:

```
    This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread
 different from the Dispatcher thread
```

This code give me the same error:

```
var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
uiContext.Send(x => ChildReviews.Clear(), null);
```

Comment: Are there several dispatchers invoved? Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53100050/7252182) answer.

Comment: On which thread did you instantiate your Observable Collection?

Comment: Yes I had this method  BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(ChildReviews, _lock)

Comment: @mm8 Yes there are several dispachers. And  the error occurs when ChildReviews is Clear in the dispatcher in another place and then here in above code. When I call only above code, it works

Comment: I've created this little helper library to reduce the pain of working with observable collections from multiple threads: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Divis.AsyncObservableCollection/ It basically works by initializing the collection with a delegate that runs all the operations through a dispatcher, so you don't have to worry about which thread you're calling it from. I know it's probably not the cleanest solution but it works just fine in all my WPF and Xamarin.Forms apps.

Comment: @Robert: You "had" `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`? And it didn't work or what? You can only clear the collection using the dispatcher that actually owns the data bound view which is obviously not  `Application.Current.Dispatcher` in your case. Please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue for further help.

Comment: @MichalDiviš thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve this problem.
First time ChildReviews was cleared in another thread:

```
   Task.Run(() => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    GetChildReviews();
                }); )
```

and then in another dispather:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    GetChildReviews();
});
```

I had to remove `Task.Run()` and now it works