# Bindings and updating from another thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, binding

I just noticed what I can update binding source from another thread and it just works.

So I prepared a demo below and my questions are:

- Why binding works? Why rising notification from another thread doesn't throws?
- Is it *legal* to update source from another thread like this?

I was always using and telling to others to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`, but maybe I simply don't know something? Maybe binding is always guaranteed to update its target in UI thread or something like this?

---

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000); // just wait long enough to ensure window is shown

            // works
            Text = "123";
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));

            // will crash with
            // System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it'
            textBox.Text = "123";
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to set a *source* property on a background thread. The framework handles the marshaling for you under the hood.

If you however try to add or remove items from a source collection, it's a different story:

[How to update only a property in an observable collection from thread other than dispatcher thread in WPF MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258222/how-to-update-only-a-property-in-an-observable-collection-from-thread-other-than/51260357#51260357)

*Target* properties, or more exactly properties of `DependencyObjects`, can only be accessed on the thread on which the object was originally created though. But you don't need to use a dispatcher to set view model properties from a background thread.

Comment: Updating (e.g. calling `Add()` method) of **bound** `ObservableCollection<T>` will indeed throw (different) exception. Assigning a **new** instance or if it's unbound will just work. Interesting... Any kind of proof what assigning can be done in any (namely in non-ui) thread?

Comment: @Sinatr: You should be able to set data bound source properties but not modifying data bound collections.