System.NotSupportedException in WPF ObservableCollection with Dispatcher Thread Invocation
I'm developing a WPF application using the SharpClipboard library to manage clipboard items. My application listens for clipboard changes and updates an ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> in the ViewModel. However, after running the application for a few hours, I encounter the following exception:
System.NotSupportedException: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
   at ClipKeeper.Source.MVVM.ViewModel.BaseViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass315_0.<ClipboardManager_OnNewClipboardItemHandler>b__0() in C:\dev\projects\c#\ClipKeeper\ClipKeeper\Source\MVVM\ViewModel\BaseViewModel.cs:line 943
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)
   at ClipKeeper.Source.MVVM.ViewModel.BaseViewModel.ClipboardManager_OnNewClipboardItemHandler(ClipboardItem clipboardItem) in C:\dev\projects\c#\ClipKeeper\ClipKeeper\Source\MVVM\ViewModel\BaseViewModel.cs:line 941

Setup:
MainWindow.xaml.cs

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BaseViewModel ViewModel;
}

BaseViewModel.cs
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ClipboardManager clipboardManager;

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        clipboardManager.OnNewClipboardItemHandler += ClipboardManager_OnNewClipboardItemHandler;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> HistoryClipboards
    {
        get { return historyClipboards; }
        set
        {
            historyClipboards = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ClipboardManager ClipboardManager
    {
        get { return clipboardManager; }
        set
        {
            clipboardManager = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ClipboardManager));
        }
    }

    private void ClipboardManager_OnNewClipboardItemHandler(ClipboardItem clipboardItem)
    {
        HistoryClipboards.Insert(0, clipboardItem);
    }
}


ClipboardManager.cs
public class ClipboardManager
{

    private readonly SharpClipboard sharpClipboard;
    public event OnNewClipboardItemDelegate? OnNewClipboardItemHandler;

    private void SharpClipboard_ClipboardChanged(object? sender, ClipboardChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentClipboardItem = new ClipboardItem(
            contentTypes: ContentTypes.Text,
            data: Helpers.GetObjectBytes(e.ContentType, text),
            title: e.SourceApplication.Title ?? "N/A",
            path: path,
            info: $"{text.Length:N0} characters",
            isEditable: true,
            isWhiteSpace: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text));

        OnNewClipboardItemHandler?.Invoke(currentClipboardItem);
    }

    public ClipboardManager()
    {
        sharpClipboard = new SharpClipboard();
        sharpClipboard.ClipboardChanged += SharpClipboard_ClipboardChanged;
    }
}

Problem
The application throws a System.NotSupportedException when I attempt to add a new clipboard item to the ObservableCollection in the ClipboardManager_OnNewClipboardItemHandler method. This issue occurs sporadically after the application has been running for a while. Interestingly, restarting the application temporarily resolves the issue, but the exception reoccurs after some time.
Attempted Solution
To address this, I wrapped the insertion logic in a Dispatcher call to ensure it runs on the UI thread:
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    HistoryClipboards.Insert(0, clipboardItem);
});

However, this solution doesn't seem to be foolproof, as the problem reoccurs after some time.
Question
What might be causing this exception, even when using the Dispatcher?
Is there a better approach to safely update the ObservableCollection from the clipboard event handler, considering it runs on a different thread?
How can I ensure that my application handles these updates without hitting the System.NotSupportedException again?
UPDATE
I created this:
private readonly object historyClipboardsLock = new();

historyClipboards = new ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem>();
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(HistoryClipboards, historyClipboardsLock);

And when when try to add item into my collection:
lock (historyClipboardsLock)
{
    HistoryClipboards.Insert(0, clipboardItem);
}

And this exception still occurs
EDIT
This happening again, The only place I found with Dispatcher is this:
public async void Execute(object? parameter)
{
    if (parameter is TextBox textBox)
    {
        ViewModel.ShowLoadingMessage();

        // Get the search text from the TextBox.
        string searchText = textBox.Text;

        // Update the ViewModel property to show or hide hint text.
        ViewModel.ShowHintText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText);

        // Perform the filtering operation asynchronously.
        var filteredItems = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var itemSourceList = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = ViewModel.HistoryClipboards };
            ICollectionView collectionView = itemSourceList.View;

            // Define the filter predicate to match clipboard items containing the search text.
            var filteredPredicate = new Predicate<object>(item => ((ClipboardItem)item).DataToText().Contains(searchText));
            collectionView.Filter = filteredPredicate;
            return collectionView;
        });

        ViewModel.HideLoadingMessage();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            ViewModel.BindFilter(filteredItems);
        });
    }
}


"What might be causing this exception, even when using the Dispatcher?" - that is unclear, it should just work with Dispatcher. However, consider using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization as explained in the answer to the duplicate question.

I try this solution, Please see my updater

And you have set EnableCollectionSynchronization before? As explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Yes, I just add it into my update, You can see it

Also do i need to use this lock also in Property Setter and delete item from the collection ?

See the Remarks in the documentation: Synchronize all access from the application to the collection using that mechanism. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21720638/1136211

I did the same as  stackoverflow link that you provided, Also I add using this lock in the Property Setter and Delete item, I hope this will solve my issue

"I hope this will solve my issue" - probably not. The problem should not have occured in the first place when you had used the Dispatcher. Something beyond what you have shown here seems to be happening.

Why do you think that Something beyond what happening ? And why do you think that using EnableCollectionSynchronization won't help ?

Because of "This issue occurs sporadically after the application has been running for a while"

Are you doing something with multiple UI threads? On the face of it it appears that whatever is bound to the Observable collection is on a different dispatcher from the rest of the application. That is very unusual and only occurs to my knowledge when you have multiple windows each with their own UI threads.

Instead of Application.Current.Dispatcher, maybe try seeing if you can get a Dispatcher instance from the actual control that's bound to the collection. If that eliminates the problem then there is something going on with multiple dispatchers. But if it doesn't work, then frankly the behavior is inexplicable.

Yes I found d place with Dispatcher and Thread, See my edit

Your "event handler" is being called by a library (SharpClipboard) that is probably doing it's own threading. Instead of "inserting" to the collection from the handler, add to a (thread safe) ConcurrentQueue that is serviced from the "client" side with a (background) worker that reports on the UI thread (for example).

Your last edit reveals the problem. You're creating the CollectionViewSource on a background thread, inside the Task.Run block. That's why making collection changes via the Dispatcher isn't working - the change is occurring on the UI thread, but the bound object is on a background thread. It's an interesting (if dangerous) quirk of WPF that it will let you create DispatcherObjects on any thread, even non-UI threads, but this should almost never be done.
My advice is drop all the background thread usage entirely and do all this in the UI thread. In other words, remove Task.Run and execute everything in your last "EDIT" block on the UI thread. You also don't need to wrap ViewModel.BindFilter(filteredItems); in a dispatcher call either. If the filter operation is very slow for some reason, find another solution, but it's very unlikely in-memory filtering of clipboard data will be so massive an operation as to necessitate asynchronous treatment.
Finally, then, SharpClipboard_ClipboardChanged may or may not need to invoke the Dispatcher depending on whether it's executed on a background thread. I couldn't say without knowing more about that library, but I suspect not.
